# Automate standard comments?

Tags: support, site-tools, comments

From a comment exchange under a closed question:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a Mathematica issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of Mathematica is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for Mathematica.SE. – m_goldberg
>
> @m_goldberg do you have a script for this particular standard comment of yours? – LLlAMnYP
>
> @LLlAMnYP. Yes, and for several others as well. – m_goldberg
>
> ... *further enquiries which did not satisfy my interest ...*

If one looks around here on meta, he can find [this accepted answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/26956) for a tool that converts stuff like `\[Alpha]` to the appropriate unicode character.

There is a strong demand for standard greeting comments and/or responses, as exemplified by these [two](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597/26956) [threads](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/138/26956).

I would have thought that by following the links in [this question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1442/26956) I would have found a relevant link to the script used by @m_goldberg, but I was to be disappointed:

> @LLlAMnYP. I do use a publicly available tool. It is called BBEdit and is commercially available for OS X. But since it is not a tool I created, I can't make it available to others. – m_goldberg

So my question is:
**Is there a convenient, easy to use tool, like the Greasemonkey script for unicode characters, but to insert standard comments, or is everybody using good old Copy-Paste?**

Comment: [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) can be used to define hotstrings: you type in the short hotstring (e.g. `canned1` or whatever) and it is immediately replaced by the full comment text. Autohotkey is super easy to setup and use, its free and it is open source.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Looking at its feature, this seems to be a potential answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I misunderstood your comments. I thought you were asking me how I generated and managed the set of closing comments that I use repeatedly. I have a commercial tool that let's me choose one of these comments from a menu and then places the chosen comment onto my system's clipboard. From there I just paste into the closing dialog.

I also thought that you wanted me to make my canned comments available to others so they could use them. I seem to be mistaken about that too.

I am sorry I provoked you into what seems a futile effort. I say "futile" because I know of no tool such as you describe in your question.

Comment: Your canned comments are useful and would be good contributions to the linked questions. As for futility, I would think it's conceivable that someone of the many members has a more open-sourced solution.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. I hope you are right that someone else can give a solution. But I am pessimistic about your chances, which is why I wrote "seems futile".